# What transformer should I use for high power switching?

Tags: power-supply, power, circuit-design, transformer, switch-mode-power-supply

I'd like to build a high power switch mode power supply. I'm still not entirely sure how to do this, but I am playing around with some circuits for now.

My thoughts was to have input voltage (wall outlet, 120 VAC) running into a rectifier and capacitor (~170 V) and into a pulse transformer, then to a MOSFET. The gate of the MOSFET would be controlled by a pulse to control the duty cycle (probably just an Arduino circuit for now until I figure out how to build a feedback circuit eventually).

Now I know I want the output voltage to be around 20V and the output current to be 30A (yes I need lots of current!)

The issue is I don't know which transformer to use. I know I need a 1:8 transformer. I can control the output voltage with the duty cycle to make adjustments, but I am worried about frying the transformer if I run too much current into it. The transformers I found on Digikey do not seem to show the maximum power or current that can go through them.

I'd appreciate if anyone can help by sending links to transformers that can work for this application and perhaps help explain how to choose transformers or where they show the power or current amounts. I need to get that 30A current, that is what is important. I want to build this for 20~22V and 600~800W application.

Thanks for any advice as I am not that knowledgeable in circuits.

[image]

Comment: Don’t start with such a high power. You will end very soon. Try build a small one and then you can attempt a 30A. When I type already: the core volume depends not on power but a switching frequency also. Higher frequency -> smaller core.

Comment: The circuit topology you have drawn will not work. Choice of transformer is the least of your problems. More components are needed to make it work either as a forward converter, or as a flyback.

Comment: Consider that simple analogue DC voltage regulator design is like building a little boat and floating around on a lake then, consider that an off-line AC power converter design is like building an aeroplane and flying it. Where do you think your skills lie?

Comment: If you ppl do not know, just dont bother commenting on this post. thank you

Answer (score 1):

To be safe you better galvanicly isolate your MOSFET from your Arduino with perhaps a small transformer of fast optocoupler. Do this to avoid electrocution. Now you can think about not blowing up the MOSFET. Think about your peak currents and what limits them. Also think about the peak DS voltage which will be spikey. At these powers I use half bridge. Your micro will not have enough grunt to drive a big FET. If you underdrive it you will blow the FET. You have lots to think about and really it is a learning exercise not a money thing on this site.

Comment: If you ppl do not know, just dont bother commenting on this post. thank you.